# Hot to structure data for 1 on 1 competition game

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models

My question is about how to best structure my dataset for a competition between 2 players of a game (for the purposes of prediction of future game winners). There will potentially be hundreds of participants in this dataset. I currently have the set as:

```
WinnerName, LoserName, WinnerStat1, WinnerStat2,... ,LoserStat1, LoserStat2, ...
```

In my mind, I'd tend to think about this as 'profiling' (for want of a better word).  For each record:

- For the winner, observe the statistics 1...n and update his profile
- For the loser, ditto
- Then, to predict the outcome of a match based on two names only, compare their profiles.

At first glance, this is probably not the approach R would foster - in all the R tutorials I've done, this kind of 'different records could well belong to different entities' doesn't tend to come up. This leads me to think that my dataframe isn't structured in an R-friendly way. My initial thought was to have each participant in a separate dataframe, but I'd have hundreds - and, again, something doesn't feel right about this approach (even if I can't put my finger on what, exactly).

**Does anyone have any advice on how to go about structuring the dataset?**

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @gung...I don't believe I'm asking about how software works - I'm asking about how best to layout the data to answer the questions I want. This is a design question more than anything. Possibly ignorance on my part, but I don't believe I have an underlying statistics issue. What makes you think I do?

Comment: A question about how to design a study, or a structure a dataset to answer a question, is a statistical question at heart, IMO. But you want to emphasize & clarify that, distinct from "how to go about this in R", which would be off topic here.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what you mean. Thanks, I'll edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As I understand you want to use supervised learning algorithm, then
  you need target variable (outcome).
- WinnerName and LoserName can't provide any useful information to
  classifier, you don't need these columns in your dataset. Players are fully described by (Stat1, Stat2, ..., StatN)
- One row represents one game.

Suggested dataset structure:

```
Player1Stat1 ... Player1StatN Player2Stat1 ... Player2StatN Outcome
```

where the outcome is 1 if Player1 has won, and 0 (or -1) if Player2.

Now you need additional function which puts in correspondence player name and his Stats1..StatsN vector.

*userName -> [Stats1..StatsN]:*

```
create.stats.vector <- function(playerName){
    # Your profile access code.
    result.vector <- get.stats.vector.from.database.or.text.file(name) 
    return(result.vector)
}
```

Now you can create dataset rows by two names:

```
# One dataset row for learning:
c(create.stats.vector('John'), create.stats.vector('Ivan'), Outcome) 
# One dataset row for prediction
c(create.stats.vector('John'), create.stats.vector('Ivan'))
```

**EXAMPLE**

Suppose you have 3 players:

```
get.stats.vector.from.database.or.text.file <- function(name)
{
  if (name=='A') return(c(1, 0.4, 0.5))
  if (name=='B') return(c(0, 0.3, 0.7))
  if (name=='C') return(c(0, 1.2, 0.1))

  return (c(1, 0.3, 0)) 
}
```

Suppose you have 2 games (2 rows of data):

```
df <- data.frame(c("A", "C"), c("B", "A"), c(0, 1),
             row.names=c("Game1", "Game2"))
colnames(df) <- c("Player1name", "Player2name", "Outcome")
```

You can create stats vectors for each row of this dataframe:

```
create.fm.row <- function(x){
 return(c(create.stats.vector(x[1]),
          create.stats.vector(x[2]), x[3]) )
}
feature.matrix <-t(apply(df, 1, create.fm.row))
```

Now you have feature matrix and can apply machine learning methods.

*Note*

As I understand you want to use *for* loop for feature matrix creation. But, as noted here [[r-bloggers.com]](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/), usage of loops in general should be avoided in R

Comment: thanks for your thoughts! so, I would still need to iterate over all the players stats in a for loop. This means I would need to iterate over the entire dataset n times, where n is the number of unique players in the dataset. have I understood you correctly?

Comment: I've reread question, maybe I misunderstood you. 
What kind of stats do you have: do they describe player performance in one game (like number of points scored ), or in all games (like overall accuracy)?

Comment: the former. agreed about your comment on avoiding for loops in R - that's why I said it didn't feel R-friendly